# Google Drive API - Missing Parent Field

Tags: google-drive-api

The following request returns the "parents" field for each file as expected:

REQUEST

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=teamDrive&includeTeamDriveItems=true&q=(mimeType+contains+%22document%22)+and+(trashed+%3D+false)&supportsTeamDrives=true&teamDriveId=0AF36YeSWsu3dUk9PVA&fields=files(headRevisionId%2Cid%2Cparents)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

RESPONSE

```
{
 "files": [
  {
   "id": "1pULO-raKOEE2gHawEEd89UdKYqvX1cwFPYHwrJ9kgn4",
   "parents": [
    "0Bwy7SlKkxnwQRld6RWljU0Y4TG8"
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "1A1lyNy_ZRfyaYrpqLtY-DiuOH_Wh2-qso4pml8zceN0",
   "parents": [
    "0B4jAnSzS-VxlLTA4WWtIdkJ2NGs"
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "1yYnu_LQF71_2hbsHFjylyXl_71oT9xw3BymtdQj9DWM",
   "parents": [
    "0B4jAnSzS-VxlLTFEaktzX1BjNW8"
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "1ln2anvndwQ6PQUe3OLwaQH3T8lvDTX0o-TeY3SaG5Kg",
   "parents": [
    "0B4jAnSzS-VxlSFd5UERwMTY1Ym8"
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

If I eliminate the "headRevisionId" field from the request, I also lose the "parents" field from response on 3 of the 4 files:

REQUEST

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=teamDrive&includeTeamDriveItems=true&q=(mimeType+contains+%22document%22)+and+(trashed+%3D+false)&supportsTeamDrives=true&teamDriveId=0AF36YeSWsu3dUk9PVA&fields=files(id%2Cparents)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

RESPONSE

```
{
 "files": [
  {
   "id": "1pULO-raKOEE2gHawEEd89UdKYqvX1cwFPYHwrJ9kgn4",
   "parents": [
    "0Bwy7SlKkxnwQRld6RWljU0Y4TG8"
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "1A1lyNy_ZRfyaYrpqLtY-DiuOH_Wh2-qso4pml8zceN0"
  },
  {
   "id": "1yYnu_LQF71_2hbsHFjylyXl_71oT9xw3BymtdQj9DWM"
  },
  {
   "id": "1ln2anvndwQ6PQUe3OLwaQH3T8lvDTX0o-TeY3SaG5Kg"
  }
 ]
}
```

I have no clue why this is happening.  These files are on a Team Drive.  I have team access to view/edit all of these documents.  The only file where the "parents" field is visible in the second request is for the document that I personally created.  Why should this matter?  I can see the "parents" *if and only if* the "headRevisionId" is also part of the request.  Can anyone explain?

Thanks,
Shannon

Comment: Seems related to this [reported possible bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62671922).

Comment: Yes it does. Interesting that both problems have to do with Team Drives.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: You're welcome. :) I suggest starring it and actually putting the details you have there, specifically, where adding `headRevisionId` returns the `parents` parameter.